# Connecting QGIS with azure adls gen2 storage

Tags: qgis, azure

I am wondering if it is possible to link QGIS with azure blob storage, in particular azure data lake gen2 storage. When looking at the add vector layer, there seems to be an option to connect to "Microsoft Azure blob". But it requires a "bucket or container" field and an "object key" field. I cannot figure out what I should put here.

Does anybody have experience with this who could tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

To load data from Azure into QGIS, the first thing you will need to do is provide QGIS with your Azure Storage Connection String. You can set this as an environment variable from QGIS by going to:

Settings > Options > System > Environment

Then set AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING as a new environment variable (using your connection string as the Value).

After that has been set you connect to files in your Azure container by setting:

- 'bucket or container' to the name of the container where your files are stored
- 'object key' to the name of the file that you would like to import into QGIS

There is full a step-by-step tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN0nAl7cd-Y